# Event click fires multiple times after success get data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple script like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function getData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/path/to/file',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    var text = response.jsontitle;

                    $('#link').attr('class', '');
                    $('#link').attr('class', text);

                    // Second, Third, Fourth .... after get data
                    // Click fires 2, 3, 4 .... after get data
                    $('#link').on('click', function() {
                        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
                    })
                }
            });
        }

        var refreshData = setInterval(getData, 5000);

        getData();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I want the click event to occur only once per time interval. Currently, however, the click event occurs as many times as `getData()` occurs.

For example, if the `getData()` occurs twice, then click event will happen twice as well.

Comment: You are binding on click n number of times in ajax success handler. Why not take on click outside success function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first unbind event then bind, if you want to use inside success callback function

```
$('#link').off('click').on('click'....
```

OR better to bind event once outside of callback function